# What's wrong with my Batch Apex + Http callout get method?

Tags: apex, batch, callout, http

I think my code is wrong.

Last version of my HttpGet/Callout code (it works):
[How to use HttpGet service to get a list of objects and create them?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/239876/how-to-use-httpget-service-to-get-a-list-of-objects-and-create-them) Now I try to make it batch. My Execute Anonymous Window part: `Id batchJobId = Database.executeBatch(new Callout(), 300);`

In debug window I get just 'Start!'. Why I can't get another debug's string? Now my code doesn't work (I also can't get recorts from HttpGet).

Code:

```
global class Callout implements Database.Batchable<sObject>, Database.AllowsCallouts {    
public String query = 'SELECT First_Name__c, Last_Name__c FROM AnotherItem__c';
global Database.QueryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext BC) {
    System.debug('Start!');
    return Database.getQueryLocator(query);
}

public class Callout {    
public static String webTokenBody(){
    String requestBody = 'my_web_token_string';
    return request;
}

public class webTok{
    public String webToken{get;set;}    
}

public static HttpRequest createRequestForToken(String service){
    String requestBody = webTokenBody();
    HttpRequest ourRequest = new HttpRequest();
    ourRequest.setBody(requestBody);
    ourRequest.setMethod(service);
    ourRequest.setEndpoint('https://my.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/token');
    return ourRequest;
}

public static HttpRequest createRequestForService(String token, String method){
    HttpRequest finalRequest = new HttpRequest();
    finalRequest.setHeader('Authorization','Bearer ' + token);
    finalRequest.setHeader('Content-Type','application/json');
    finalRequest.setHeader('accept','application/json');
    finalRequest.setMethod(method);
    finalRequest.setEndpoint('https://my.salesforce.com/services/apexrest/endpoint/');
    return finalRequest;
}

global void execute(Database.BatchableContext BC, List<AnotherItem__c> records) {
    System.debug('Process...');
    for(integer i=0; i<records.size(); i++){
        Http ourHttp = new Http();
        HttpRequest requestForToken = createRequestForToken('GET');
        HttpResponse responseToken = ourHttp.send(requestForToken);
        webTok objAuthenticationInfo = (webTok)JSON.deserialize(responseToken.getbody(), webTok.class);

        if(objAuthenticationInfo.webToken != null){
            HttpRequest requestForService = createRequestForService(objAuthenticationInfo.webToken, 'GET');
            HttpResponse responseService = ourHttp.send(requestForService);
            System.debug('ALL RECORDS:  ' + responseService.getBody());
        }
    }
}

global void finish(Database.BatchableContext BC){
    System.debug('Finish!');
}
}
```

Comment: Does the query `SELECT First_Name__c, Last_Name__c FROM AnotherItem__c` return any result? Have you tried checking this?

Comment: It can't get to the execute() method.

Comment: Are you getting proper access token

Comment: Yes. it worked without batch: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/239876/how-to-use-httpget-service-to-get-a-list-of-objects-and-create-them

Comment: Okay can you change the batch size as 50?
Database.executeBatch(new Callout(), 300);

You can do only 100 callouts in 1 transaction or 100callouts in excute

Comment: Yeah, tank you. I do even 10 already, but get "statusCode != 200" from HttpGet service. Debugs are ok now. But still doesn't work.

Comment: Whats the debug of this?
System.debug('ALL RECORDS:  ' + responseService.getBody());

Comment: All records of Item__c from second organization, where I have my service.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check if the AnotherItem__c object has any records or not. Also since you are writing a batch class, it would call the execute method `n/scope` times, where 'n' is the number of records fetched from the query in the `start()` method. In your case, it might not return any records so the `execute()` method won't be called at all.

Also the debugs for all the methods in a batch class are generated differently. You'll find the debug for execute method in a different log. It should have a specific name like `SerialBatchApexRangeChunkHandler` in the debug logs.

Comment: It has records, of course. I get my records for upsert from HttpGet service: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/239876/how-to-use-httpget-service-to-get-a-list-of-objects-and-create-them So I don't understand why I still haven't that.

Comment: A batch class would work only when it gets a result from the query that you make in the start method. In your case, the query is `SELECT First_Name__c, Last_Name__c FROM AnotherItem__c`. If this does not return any results, it will never call the execute method.

The answer that you linked fetches the records *from a different org* and not the one in which your batch is running.

Comment: Thank you. I fixed a number of records. Now it calls execute method. But I can't get changed records from HttpGet anyway :(

Answer (score 1):

A transaction can do at max 100 callouts, so the Batch size should be less than or equal to 100

Now, I can also see you are doing the callout to get accesToken in loop, you can move it away from loop

```
global void execute(Database.BatchableContext BC, List<AnotherItem__c> records) {
    System.debug('Process...');
    HttpRequest requestForToken = createRequestForToken('GET');
    HttpResponse responseToken = ourHttp.send(requestForToken);
    webTok objAuthenticationInfo = (webTok)JSON.deserialize(responseToken.getbody(), webTok.class);
    for(integer i=0; i<records.size(); i++){
        Http ourHttp = new Http();


        if(objAuthenticationInfo.webToken != null){
            HttpRequest requestForService = createRequestForService(objAuthenticationInfo.webToken, 'GET');
            HttpResponse responseService = ourHttp.send(requestForService);
            System.debug('ALL RECORDS:  ' + responseService.getBody());
        }
    }
}
```

**Database.executeBatch(new Callout(), 99);**

Would be the optimal value for batch execution.